# Proper way to make android tabs in ice cream sandwhich with the least amount of code

Tags: android

so I've been searching without end to find a simple way to make tabs in ice cream sandwhich. It seems like Tab Activity is deprecated and the Fragment example on the official android website seems a bit much. The android tutorial I'm going through right now seems to make tabs a big deal, but extends TabActivity. Can someone please point me in the right direction? Some example code would be appreciated.

Comment: To others: I disagree with the close vote. I think this is a beginner asking for a way to implement tabs (and possibly view pagers) with something other than the stock Android APIs (stock Android tabs sometimes can be challenging to rookies). he probably just didn't express himself well enough. At least that's what I got. He probably should have searched better, but still...

Comment: +1 Ah, true. I'm generally very generous with people beginning (and I remember having problems with tabs way back then), but you're right, I didn't see his membership info.

Comment: Am generous too **provided** they have shown effort on their part, if not...well..hence I linked to [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: Hey guys, OP here. I'm seventeen and trying to finish up highschool. I've been programming for a while, but am new to android. I would appreciate the help. I don't mean to come off as lazy.

Comment: Hi OP, don't want to be sounding harsh or anything - not personal. Just something to bear in mind, there's a lot of similar questions in different tags that I have dealt with and come across as "Gimme gimme code plskthxbai" without any research. Its great to see someone like you on this, its a community, but with a community that comes with rules. As part of community, effort has to be shown, there's no short cuts whatsoever regardless, this also applies to life itself as well. :) For now, upvote David's answer and that will lead you on a journey of Android and enjoy it :) That's all :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) has support for tabs. I'd suggest it if you have problems implementing it using the stock Android APIs.

It comes with source, app examples (downloadable from Market/Play) and source examples. The examples are really small (code size) and simple, yet detailed. It can't get any better really.

Comment: I upvoted to encourage the OP to see and understand the nature of this SO community :) And yeah, ActionBarSherlock does indeed kick some ass ;)

Comment: *"I upvoted to encourage the OP to see and understand the nature of this SO community"* --- me sad. :p 

...
(j/k, j/k.)